# External networking with Docker Swarm and Stacks

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I've currently got two fairly vanilla CentOS 7 boxes that are running under a Docker Swarm, one a master and the other joined to it. In that swarm, I want to have a stack running that will essentially be my Plex / multimedia system. I've got the [docker_compose.yml](https://gist.github.com/Chiggins/1852f1517b9a40a3cb6bb2f9595c69f8) file for that linked. I can deploy the file to the swarm using the following command:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml plexsystem
```

That works fine, it deploys the containers like you would expect. The issue I'm having is that the containers do not have external internet access, so if the container needs to download any files or interact with APIs, they fail. I interact with containers with `docker exec -it container /bin/bash` and try to ping out, and it always fails.

What do I need to add or change to my `docker-compose.yml` file so that my networking can work and I can finally get my stack working as it should. I've been banging my head with this one and I cannot figure out how to get swarm networking. Thank you very much!

Comment: Could be helpful - "https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/866#issuecomment-19218300"

Is it related to DNS or the packets are getting blocked? OR both TCP/UDP getting blocked?

Comment: @vivekyad4v I don't believe it's just DNS. I've tried to ping 8.8.8.8, Google DNS, and that wouldn't go through. It seems like everything is not making its way out.

Comment: What type of docker network is it? `docker network ls`. Firewall blocking?

Comment: Did you get this working ?  Also very interested in this.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your docker daemon file and look for the iptables parameter configuration. Most probably it is set to false and hence it is not able to access the internet.

> --iptables=false prevents the Docker daemon from adding iptables rules. If multiple daemons manage iptables rules, they may overwrite rules set by another daemon. Be aware that disabling this option requires you to manually add iptables rules to expose container ports. If you prevent Docker from adding iptables rules, Docker will also not add IP masquerading rules, even if you set --ip-masq to true. Without IP masquerading rules, Docker containers will not be able to connect to external hosts or the internet when using network other than default bridge.